# show that function $x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ is continuous on $[1/2,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to show that function $f(x)= x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ is continuous on $[1/2,1]$.

I know that function $f$ is differensiable at $x$ for all $x\in [1/2,1]$. Hence $f$ is continuous on $[1/2,1]$. But I do not how to show $f$ continuous using $\epsilon-\delta$.

Please help me.

EDIT: show it is absolutly continuous on $[1/2,1]$

Comment: Your edit is odd, as we have the basic theorem that says that a continuous function in a *bounded* closed interval is uniformly continuous there.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:

$$|x^2\sin^2(1/x) - a^2\sin^2(1/a)| = |x^2(\sin^2(1/x)-\sin^2(1/a)) + (x^2-a^2)\sin^2(1/a)|\le$$

$$\le |\sin^2(1/x)-\sin^2(1/a)|+ |x^2-a^2|\leq 2|1/x-1/a|+2|x-a|\leq \dfrac{5|x-a|}{2}\;,\;\; a \in [1/2,1]$$ Can you continue from here?

Comment: ,note $f(x)= x^2\sin (1/x^2)$